# MySQL - Trigger IF statement using Select to AGE

Tags: mysql, sql

i don't understand what i'm doing wrong, can someone help me?

```
CREATE TABLE Pessoa(
    nome VARCHAR(25),
    nascimento DATE,
    maior_idade CHAR(1) null
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_pessoa BEFORE INSERT
ON Pessoa
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.nascimento, NOW()) AS idade FROM Pessoa p)>=18) THEN
        
        UPDATE Pessoa AS p
        SET NEW.maior_idade = 'S'
        WHERE p.nome = NEW.nome;
            
      ELSE
        UPDATE Pessoa AS p
        SET NEW.maior_idade = 'N'
        WHERE p.nome= NEW.nome;
      END IF;
END$$

INSERT INTO Pessoa (nome, nascimento) VALUES ('tiago', '1998-02-21');
```

I'm trying to create a trigger to define if when the person is over 18 years old it will be marked with 'S' and if it is under age it will be marked with 'N'.

Answer (score 1):

The deal is that you cannot read or write from the same table specified in the trigger's `ON` clause or the `ON Pessoa` portion.
The good news, is that you can refer to the `NEW` values of the `BEFORE INSERT` to do exactly what you need.

Try with this modified trigger example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_pessoa BEFORE INSERT
ON Pessoa
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, NEW.nascimento, NOW()) >= 18) THEN
        SET NEW.maior_idade = 'S';
    ELSE
        SET NEW.maior_idade = 'N';
    END IF;
END $$
```

Then with 2 insert examples:

```
INSERT INTO Pessoa (nome, nascimento) VALUES ('tiago', '1998-02-21');
INSERT INTO Pessoa (nome, nascimento) VALUES ('testr', '2010-02-21');
```

Gives the output:
[image]

[Here's a link](https://dbfiddle.uk/tP03qSym) with the trigger example to try it out. Note that the site does not deal with the `DELIMITER` use, so the delimiter handling is commented-out in the example.